# Handle loading of .net module into PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-assembly, powershell-module

I have an .NET assembly that will get imported by a Powershell session using:

```
Import-Module MyAssemblyFirst.dll
```

What I need is to automatically load another custom assembly (`MyAssemblySecond.dll`) that I know about when `MyAssemblyFirst.dll` gets imported.

The scenario I am looking for is:

```
Import-Module MyAssemblyFirst.dll
Import-Module MyAssemblySecond.dll
```

but I would rather like to have only one `Import-Module` call:

```
Import-Module MyAssemblyFirst.dll
```

...and somehow to trigger loading the second assembly as well.

The 2 assemblies do not reference each other but I am the owner of both. I'm just trying to simplify importing multiple assemblies by importing only one.

So in a broader example, I am looking to simplify a PS script like this:

```
Import-Module MyAssemblyFirst.dll
Import-Module MyAssemblySecond.dll
Import-Module MyAssemblyThird.dll
```

...

```
Import-Module MyAssemblyNth.dll
```

to a single line:

```
Import-Module MyAssemblyFirst.dll
```

**EDIT:**
The purpose for this is that based on a certain logic located in MyAssemblyFirst.dll I might want to automatically import some other assemblies that expose some new specific PS commands.

Comment: Start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx and create a manifest, I'm not sure if you'll need `RequiredModules` or `RequiredAssemblies`, try them and add the info to your question.

Comment: Looks promising, however I need if possible to load the external module from MyAssemblyFirst.dll code. Based on some logic, I might want to skip loading of MyAssemblySecond.dll and only load MyAssemblyThird.dll

Comment: Possibly this other SO question may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489494/powershell-module-manifest-automatically-loading-a-required-module

Comment: Which PowerShell version are you targeting?

Comment: PS version 4.0 minimum

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `IModuleAssemblyInitializer` interface to provide module initialization code:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Invoke, "Command1")]
    public class Command1 : Cmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            WriteObject("Command 1");
        }
    }
    public class ModuleInitializer : IModuleAssemblyInitializer {
        public void OnImport() {
            using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) {
                ps.AddCommand("Write-Host").AddArgument("Before submodule import").AddStatement().
                   AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument(".\\Assembly2.dll").AddStatement().
                   AddCommand("Write-Host").AddArgument("After submodule import").Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
’@ -OutputAssembly .\Assembly1.dll

Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Invoke, "Command2")]
    public class Command2 : Cmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            WriteObject("Command 2");
        }
    }
    public class ModuleInitializer : IModuleAssemblyInitializer {
        public void OnImport() {
            using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) {
                ps.AddCommand("Write-Host").AddArgument("Importing submodule").Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
’@ -OutputAssembly .\Assembly2.dll

Write-Host 'Before module import'
Import-Module .\Assembly1.dll
Write-Host 'After module import'

Invoke-Command2
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone wondering about the lifetime of the `IModuleAssemblyInitializer` object... I was hoping it would stay live during the duration of while the DLL is loaded by powershell. However, the instance lasts just long enough for the `OnImport` call (modulo GC).